# DT Speed and Performance Options For Filtered Datatables

Tags: r, performance, dt

Using `library(DT)` to produce a table with many rows,  I encounter a long delay between filter selection and visibility of the filtered table.  Are there options that you might recommend for optimal speed between filter selection and table display?

A smaller resulting file size would be a bonus, too.

I am filtering using `library(crosstalk)` and `filter_select()` as the data is shared across a few groups, if that impacts the recommendations at all.

Filtering is being handled by:

```
bscols(filter_checkbox("Var_A","Var_A",shared_data,~Var_A),
filter_select("Var_B","Var_B", shared_data,~Var_B))
```

As it stands, I'm using:

```
datatable(shared_data, options = list(dom = 'Bfrtip',pageLength = 15, autoWidth = TRUE,searchHighlight=TRUE))
```

Thank you for any recommendations you may have.

Comment: I assume you're doing this in a `shiny` app? Why do you think the slowdown is related to `DT` rather than the filtering operation (which seems more likely to me)?

Comment: I'm generating a standalone html file to avoid using any server.  You make a good point!  Slowdown could be coming from the filtering operation.  I have one `filter_checkbox` filter and one `filter_select` filter, and both are essential, so I was curious about tweaking `datatable` instead.  Also, I tend to use `datatable` often and was hoping for a general "this-is-the-best-set-of-options-for-performance" answer.  Any filtering recommendations would of course be welcome as well.